# javascript syntaxs not working

Tags: javascript, syntax

the biggest struggle when it comes to the basic three languages it javascript.
i have been struggling to actually do anything with javascript because everything i am typing brings up an error or incorrect syntax.
i have been checking my case and in the end i have literally copied javascript directly from w3 just to see if they work.
the javascript code still is not working, and i'm starting to get really frustrated because their syntax is literally perfect.
my main syntax issues are.

```js
if (t <= 5) {
  var x = "random";
} else {
  var x = "alsorandom"
};

//as well as

document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = x;/*used to work, but it keeps failing*/
/*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null*/

window.setInterval(function(){
  var p+=1
}, 5000);
//Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +=
//copied directly from this site
```

i am using a new version of google chrome and typing it up on a html file via a text document.
please inform me of the potential problem and i will try and fill you in on any missing information if you need more.

Comment: w3schools is a worst source to learn programming. First read the language  spec before digging into any tutorial (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript for general information and links to resources)

Comment: really? thats how i learned basic html and css.

Comment: `html` and `css` is not a science but a `markup language`.

Comment: read this,please: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Comment: If you were first read the language specification and learn what is the variable scope then you would never copy and paste the code above and post this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your first error should be inside this test:

```
if (document.getElementById("name")) {}
```

That's how you will know the element really exist before using it.

For your second error, I would try to init p outside the function so it will begin with a value, and also you are missing a semicolon at the end of the line (`;`).

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it is giving error to me in  `var p+=1`. I think you should need to replace it with `var p=p+1` and it solved my error.

If you still getting error paste your complete code with error screenshot.

Please let me know if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Before going to use the operator += you first declare the variable. That causes the error in your code. Try this one.

```js
  function MyMethod()
  {
   var p=0;
   var t=2;
   if (t <= 5) {
   var x = "random";
   } else {
   var x = "alsorandom"
   };
   
   //as well as
   
   document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = x;/*used to work, but it keeps failing*/
   /*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null*/
   
   window.setInterval(function(){
    p+=1;
   }, 5000);
  }
```

```html
<span id="name"> </span>
<input id="Test" type="button" value="Test Click" onclick="MyMethod();"></input>
```